# jQuery UI Sortable not recognizing dropped item in array

Tags: lightning, jquery, ui

I'm trying to use jQuery UI Sortable to create records, and to enable the user to change the order of created records.  The problem I am having is that upon drop, the array excludes the item dropped.  Here is my code:

FIRST SORTABLE LIST (created upon load)

```
<div style="width: 48%; display: inline-block">
<div id="TimeList">
    <div style="max-height: 360px; overflow-y: auto; ">
        <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.pageComp}" var="comp" indexVar="key">
                <li class="timeDrop" id="{!comp.key}">
                    <div class="w-row" style="">
                        <div class="w-col w-col-2">
                            <span class="moveIcon" onmouseup="{!c.DropItem}"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w-col w-col-10">
                            <ui:outputText class="timeDrop" value="{!comp.value}" mouseup="{!c.DropItem}" click="{!c.ClickItem}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </aura:iteration>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

SECOND SORTABLE LIST (list is created from existing records)

```
<div name="addItems" style="width: 48%; display: inline-block; float: right;">
<ul id="additionals" class="connectedSortable">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.existItems}" var="eComp" indexVar="key">
        <li class="existDrop" id="{!eComp.Id}">
            <div class="w-row" style="">
                <div class="w-col w-col-2">
                    <span class="moveIcon" onmouseup="{!c.DropItem}"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="w-col w-col-7">
                    <ui:outputText class="existDrop" value="{!eComp.Name}" click="{!c.ClickItem}" />
                </div>
                <div class="w-col w-col-3">
                    <lightning:button aura:id="{!eComp.Id}" variant="brand" label="Edit" class="" onclick="{!c.editComponent}" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </aura:iteration>
</ul>
```

THE CONTROLLER

```
ScriptsLoaded: function(component, event, helper) {
        //creates list
        helper.onInit(component, event, helper);

        $("#sortable1, #additionals").sortable({
            cursorAt: { top: 165 },
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
            handle: '.moveIcon',
            dropOnEmpty: true
        }).disableSelection();
},

DropItem: function(component, event, helper) {

        $("#sortable1, #additionals").sortable("refresh");

        var idsInOrder = $("#sortable1").sortable("toArray");
        console.log(idsInOrder);

        var theID = '';
        var selected = [];
        $('#sortable1 li').each(function() {
            selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
            theID = selected.toString();
        });
        console.log(theID);
}
```

This produces the following console logs.

If I simply click on the item:
(5) ["Hdr", "Rch", "Vid", "Img", "Col"]
Hdr,Rch,Vid,Img,Col

If I actually drop the item:
(4) ["Rch", "Vid", "Img", "Col"]
Hdr,Rch,,Vid,Img,Col

For the actual drop, I dropped Hdr between Rch and Vid.  You'll notice the ,, where Hdr should be, and that Hdr has not changed position.  If I simply click on the Item after actually dropping, it displays the correct number in the array and in the correct order.

I added the `$("#sortable1, #additionals").sortable("refresh");` in hopes that it would recognize the new order after a drop, but it doesn't seem to be making much difference.

Comment: Is this a SF question or a JQueryUI question? JQueryUI questions are better suited for Stackoverflow, even if they are on the SF platform.

Comment: @gNerb I wondered that myself, and was thinking of posting it on overflow as well... I didn't know if it was an issue with the way SF interacts with the DOM, or some other lightning specific problem.  Do you think I should move it to overflow?

Comment: It can't hurt to ask it over there, but you're right, lightning is annoying in how it access the DOM. I supposed it's not impossible that it's interfering with JQueryUI.

Comment: I have ran into issues with sorting when using aura iteration, not 100% sure this is your issue.. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000ep3yQAA

Comment: I added my question to overflow as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046997/jquery-ui-sortable-not-recognizing-dropped-item-in-array

@EricSSH I'll have to research that more, but it looks like a different problem at first glance.

Comment: @gNerb I created a button to replace the onmouseup function on the actual item, and the behavior is as hoped for when I press the button after moving one of the items.  Would this support that it is a DOM issue?